# Exporting to CSV places data on one line instead of on new lines

Tags: php, javascript, export-to-csv

I export data to a CSV and while I use `"\r\n"` it just outputs the data on one line rather than each set of data on its own new line under the header line, ie:

```
name | address | phone | email | greg | 2 old street | 09236462942 | greg343@gmail.com | michael | 2 new street | 0927464623 | michael343@gmail.com | ...
```

Code is as follows:

**JS**

```
var file = "Database.csv";

allData=name+","+address+","+phone+","+email;
        allData=allData.replace(/[\\]/g,'');
        saving();

function saving(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'save.php',
        timeout: 5000,
        data: { data: allData, filename: file },
        error: function() {localStorage["allData"]=allData; wiadomosc("Internet conection error. But don't worry, your data will be stored when conection will be stable.");},
        success: function() {localStorage["allData"]="";}
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["filename"]) == true && isset($_POST["data"]) == true){
    $fp = fopen($_POST["filename"], "a+");

    if($fp !== null){
        fputs($fp, $_POST["data"] . "\r\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try putting the line break before the data, that way you don't rely on the previously written data to include a line break: fputs($fp, "\r\n" . $_POST["data"]); Also, you really really shouldn't allow specifying any file as a target like this with a POST parameter.

Comment: @ajshort: Tried that and it shoves the data below but to the far right of the csv. I've specified the file as it's used as internal data collection rather that a publicly available app.

Answer (score 1):

`allData` seems like a global variable. Depending on the rest of you code almost anything can happen. You should explicitly pass `allData` to `saving`. And debug on browsers side (e.g. with Firebug) and on server side (e.g. with Netbeans).

Also this line is **pure evil**!

```
$fp = fopen($_POST["filename"], "a+");
```

That way you can overwrite almost anything on your system (server)!

And don't check `isset($_POST["filename"]) == true`. Either do `isset($_POST["filename"]) === true` (which would not be need in this case) or just do `isset($_POST["filename"])`.

EDIT:

This should make you avoid some problems in JS:

```
var allData=name+","+address+","+phone+","+email;
        allData=allData.replace(/[\\]/g,'');
        saving(allData);

function saving(allData){
    $.ajax({...
```

And this in PHP:

```
function mk_safe_filename($name, $allow_subfolders=false)
{
    $f = trim($nazwa, './\\');
    if (!$allow_subfolders)
    {
        $f = strtr($f, array('\\'=>'__', '/'=>'__', '..'=>'_', ':'=>'_'));
    }
    else
    {
        $f = strtr($f, array('\\'=>'/', '..'=>'_', ':'=>'_'));
        $f = trim($f,'/');
    }
    return $f;
}
$file_name = mk_safe_filename($_POST["filename"]);

$fp = fopen($file_name, "a+");
```

Comment: Thanks @Nux great points, thank you! Can you please provide an example by when you say "You should explicitly pass allData to saving"..

Comment: Added more info. Debugging should give you all the answers you need. Like e.g. do you need to encode data before sending.

Comment: The data didn't save at all now?

Comment: Try Netebeans. Saves a lot of headaches: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html